# Angular - How to share an app variable with all components

Tags: angular

I am making a small application with Angular7 on Front and Flask on Back, what i am tryig to do is to subscribe for a service then to save the returned data into an object type variable from inside my main `AppComponent`, then to access this varialbe in all my other components.

**Api service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  CheckApi(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/')
  }

}
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Inbox App';

  public text: object

  constructor(private data: ApiService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.data.CheckApi().subscribe(data => {
        this.text = data
        console.log(this.text)
    })
  }
}
```

And here is where i am trying to access that object from within another component:

**LoginComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<section>
    <legend class="text-center">{{ text }}</legend>
</section>
```

Comment: here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hq3uam

Comment: @JasonWhite, thanks for your interest, but why `this.apiService.data;` returns `Observable` object not data from server?

Comment: I didn't have a service to use, you could put an http call in the CheckApi method and get data.  I commented out the api call to have a working example for you to see.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz with the api call. Not test so you might have to modify a bit.

Comment: I think i got it solved, just needed to subscribe to it first :)

Comment: @JasonWhite, oh yeah, i saw the update ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done several way. Best is to use angular input

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() text: string; 
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Then you can pass variable from parent component to child component like this

```
<app-login text="yourvariable or object"></app-login>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created service for this purpose in my project which saves all data I want in objects property. And then it's possible to access it from everywhere in the project.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStorage {
  private dataStorage = {};

  addData(key: string, data: any) {
    this.dataStorage[key] = data;
  }

  getData(key: string) {
    return this.dataStorage[key];
  }

  clearData(key: string) {
    this.dataStorage[key] = undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the thing with `changed` object?

Comment: Probably a typo from when I cleaned my code for this snippet. Thank you! It's removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a public property on the App component that can be accessed from other components is not a conventional Angular way of sharing state between components, so I would advice against it.

I would either have used an @Input on the child components so that you can pass the object down to the child component, more info here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Or I would have used a Service with a BehaviorSubject as described here https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most common and straightforward method of sharing data. It works by using the @Input() decorator to allow data to be passed via the template, when there is parent child relationship. Also you can look into @ViewChild Decorator.
Also look into EventEmitter.

When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should you a shared service. When you have data that should aways been in sync, I find the RxJS BehaviorSubject very useful in this situation.
Refer below link:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/